Queueing Theory M/M/n+G Additional Performance Measure Calculations
This question builds on a prior question:
Queuing Theory M/M/n+M Number of Abandons - calculation error
But relates to the calculation of additional performance measures listed in the handout:
https://web.archive.org/web/20041110213430fw_/http://iew3.technion.ac.il/serveng/References/MMNG_formulae.pdf
I want to calculate P{W>T} (probability of waiting longer than the target time) from the primitives and building blocks listed in the handout.
So, given:

Number of Agents handling calls = 10
Average Time to Handle 1 call = 2 minutes
300 Calls per 60 minutes
Average Caller Patience = 2 minutes
Target Time to answer = 30 seconds

Yielding the following primitives:

λ = 0.0833333333
μ = 0.0083333333
θ = 0.0083333333
n = 10
ρ = λ / (n * μ) = 1.0

And the following building blocks:

$\varepsilon ≜  \frac { \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{j!} \left( \frac \lambda \mu \right)^{j} } {\frac {1} {\left(n-1\right)! } \left( \frac \lambda \mu \right)^{n-1} } $ = 3.66021568
$J =  \frac { \exp{  \{ \frac {\lambda} {\theta} \} } } {\theta} \cdot \left( \frac {\theta} {\lambda} \right)^{ \frac {n \mu} {\theta}} \cdot \gamma \left(\frac {n \mu} {\theta} , \frac {\lambda} {\theta} \right) $ = 51.9929787
$J(t) =  \frac { \exp{  \{ \frac {\lambda} {\theta} \} } } {\theta} \cdot \left( \frac {\theta} {\lambda} \right)^{ \frac {n \mu} {\theta}} \cdot \gamma \left(\frac {n \mu} {\theta} , \frac {\lambda} {\theta} e^{-\theta t} \right) $ = 24.693017054
$ \overline {G}(t) = e^{- \theta t} $ = 0.77880078

Then the probability of waiting longer than the target time should be:
$ P \{ W > t \} = \frac {\lambda \overline{G}(t)J(t)} {\varepsilon + \lambda J} $ = 0.200498643
However, the paper in section 4.3 lists the percent answered within target as 71.1% and percent abandoned within target as 8.8%.
Have I calculated P{W>t} correctly, and the paper is just multiplying 1 - P{W>t} by the 12.5% abandonment rate? In other words, does P{W>t} include both answered and abandoned calls?
If not, are all my building blocks calculated correctly?

As I was posting this as a question of which of my calculations are incorrect, I mistakenly thought I may have arrived at a correct answer, as 71.1 + 8.8  happens to equal 80% P{W<=t} I got.
However, I realize now that's not right, and I'm not getting a correct answer. So please, can anyone explain where I've gone wrong, and how to arrive at the correct P{W>t} given the equations in Mandelbaum and Zeltyn's Erlang-A performance measures?
